# Why won't new class show up in Identity Inspector/Custom Class in Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I'm having a repeating problem in Xcode 4.5 and would like to ask for help/advice.

Have been creating a new class, BIDSwitchViewController, which is a subclass of UIViewController. When I go to the Identity Inspector to layout the .xib file, of course I want to change the class it belongs to to BIDSwitchViewController, so that I can layout my objects and make my connections.

But BIDSwitchViewController doesn't show up in the dropdown list for Custom Class in Identity Inspector. So then I hardcode "BIDSwitchViewController" into the text box, but then that doesn't stick.

What am I doing wrong,and what can I do to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the .h, .m, and .xib files all set to be included in the same Xcode target (i.e. in Build Phases)?

Comment: How to check that? Have five .m files in Compile Sources, and seven items in Copy Bundle Resources. Not all the files I have created in Compile Sources; do I need to change that?

Comment: If there are .m files that you need to be built into your target they should be added to the compile phase.

Comment: Found the problem: I had View selected instead of File's Owner when I went to the Identity Inspector/ Custom Class. Once I was in File's Owner, everything showed up fine.

Answer (score 11):

My way to solve this problem is to restart my Xcode! Then all works fine. Just have a try!

Comment: this  doesnt work for me. I tried in 4.3.3 and 4.6.2  In a project I developed in earlier than 4.2  now loses the custom class!! Machine setting?? When I create a new project it is fine until I add a toolbar  button or item to toolbar then it is gone no matter what!

Comment: @sunkehappy: It worked for me, and saved me lot of grey hair. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

If restarting doesn't fix it...

1. Click on a different file
2. then go back to your `.Storyboard` or `.XIB`.

...Or try and open up your `.Storyboard` or `.XIB` in a new tab. Basically you just want to force the `IB` to reload and re-render.

Answer (score 2):

After two days of frustrations and **deleting the project then the Xcode itself** , i did not find any solution until i remembered the inheritance of my viewController , it was a viewController for a table storyboard view, but it does inherit from a UIViewController not a UITableViewController . just when i corrected , it show up .

**Just make sure that your view has the right inheritance class as the same storyboard view .**

```
class AddItemViewController: UITableViewController
```

Comment: DOH!  This is still the case two years later in Xcode 11.6.  If you start your story board by adding a Navigation Controller (like I did) Xcode will automatically add a Table View as the view controller.  Your custom class must inherit from UITableViewController.

Answer (score 1):

It is the problem of Xcode, you should switch between selecting table view and table view controller (File's owner in your practice), and the new added file names will pop out in the drop down list. 
I have tried, and it's done.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have selected "File Owner" in Placeholder before selecting the class.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this same problem as well and as Chanson Yan said click on table view or any view, then click on the main view controller (File's Owner) then check the drop-down menu again and it should appear.

Answer (score 0):

**SpecialViewController.h** and **SpecialViewController.m** may be looking as a C - file and C - header file.

I tried , right click on **SpecialViewController.h** then ***Show File Inspector***.

Then switched the ***Type*** to ***Objective-C source*** from the **C-source** , then it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the custom class in question is not a subclass of the type of class you want to associate it, it wont auto populate in Identity Inspector. That is, for view controllers the custom class should be UIViewController. For table view cells it should be a subclass of UITableViewCell.